# How HBT interferometery works?

Tags: interferometry, intensity

I am still confused about how HBT interferometry for star angular size works after reading about it on the internet and in papers. Mathematics usually does not help before I do not catch the way the experiment is done in hardware and what type of data is obtained.

Let us consider the image below.

[image]

Can someone explain step-by-step what goes on here? What actually is detected and how? How the correlation function is calculated, and how the angular size will eventually be determined.

My practical needs lie in the field of optical HBT interferometry, but first, I need to grasp ideas about stars.

Comment: do you know what AM (amplitude modulation) is in radio communications and how it can be demodulated/detected? See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation and this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732749/are-human-eyes-interferometers/732769#732769 with comments

Comment: @hyportnex, thanks for the advice. I do not see how single photon counting works for this type of interferometry because, in modern HBT, they use single photon counting, as far as I understood.

Comment: it is not just photon counting; it is the correlation of photon counting detectors, the *counter* is an integrator. In an old AM radio it was an RC filter (integrator) following the diode (mixer/multiplier), the multiplication - integration operation IS correlation.